# Generational stop and wait in garbage Collection of Java

Tags: java

I don't have good hand in java, I need your help. I just wanted to know how the "Generational stop and Wait " works in java? 
Is it used to handle garbage collection in java?

Here, GC algorithm is mark-sweep-Compact.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What GC algorithm did you mention?

Comment: Can you narrow your question? Otherwise, please read http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html and/or other resources and try to ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is "stop-the-world." Stop-the-world will occur no matter which GC algorithm you choose. Stop-the-world means that the JVM is stopping the application from running to execute a GC. When stop-the-world occurs, every thread except for the threads needed for the GC will stop their tasks. The interrupted tasks will resume only after the GC task has completed. GC tuning often means reducing this stop-the-world time.

for more details you can check below link.hop it will be helpful...
https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-java-garbage-collection

Comment: Is there any term "wait" in garbage collection ?